# Making an object manage custom data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, library

I wrote this block of code as part of a JS utility library I'm working on.  I will be thankful if someone could scan through it for eventual bugs or improvements that might be applied to it.

The idea is to create a function that will configure an object to manage its own data collection by attaching `.data()` function to it and plugging in a few utility functions to further control objects data:

```
//
//    #idb
//
//  enables an object to hold arbitrary data
//  plugges in 'data' ( fn ) property to passed object
//  handles adding, removing, modifing, replacing, iterating, checking for data
//  adds 'idb' identifier to global scope
//
//  .data()
//    # reads/manipulates objects data:
//    - if no parameters are passed returns private data store
//    - if one parameter is passed ( and its primitive ) returns it's coresponding value,
//        if plain object is provided extends data with it's props
//    - if two parameters are passed sets data key to coresponding value,
//        if second parameter is not a primitive value,
//        tries to extends private data with provided data value( extends plain objs, adds values to arrays )
//
// static fns:
//
//  .data.alter()
//    # replaces data with provided ( plain obj ) parameter
//    # @param1, object, required
//    # returns host object
//
//  .data.drop()
//    # removes data, if parameter is provided deletes it's coresponding data, otherwise empties data store
//    # @param1, scalar, optional
//    # retutns host object
//
//  .data.has()
//    # checks if data value coresponding to provided key exists
//    # @param1, scalar, required
//    # returns boolean
//
//  .data.each()
//    # iterates data store, sequentialy passes data key and it's data value to provided fn, sets fn's context to host obj
//    # @param1, function, required
//    # returns host object
//
//  .data.index()
//    # returns existing data keys as array
//    # returns array
//
//  use:
//
//    var o = idb({});
//
//    o.data("prop1", 1);
//    o.data("prop2", {p:12});
//    o.data("prop3", {p1:1, p2:{}, p3:[]});
//    o.data() -> Object, ( data object )
//    o.data('prop1'); -> 1
//    o.data('prop1', []);
//    o.data('prop1'); -> []
//    o.data.has('prop4'); -> false
//    o.data.alter({p:1,q:2});
//    o.data("p"); -> 1
//    o.data("prop1"); -> undefined
//    o.data.each(
//    function ( k, v ) {
//      console.log( k, v);
//    }
//  ); -> p 1
//         q 2
//  o.data.drop("q");
//  o.data(); -> {p:1}
//  o.data.drop();
//  o.data(); -> {}
//
;
(function(_host_) {

  var t = !0,
    f = !t,
    nl = null,
    _dbs = [],
    _db, un;

  // #helpers
  Array.prototype.each = function(fn) {
    for (
      var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (fn.call(this, i, this[i]) === f) break;
    }
    return this;
  };
  Array.prototype.has = function(v) {
    return this.indexOf(v) !== -1;
  };

  function isobj(o) {
    return o === Object(o);
  }

  function isfn(o) {
    return typeof o === 'function' && (Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === '[object Function]');
  }

  function isplainobj(o) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === '[object Object]';
  }

  function isvalid(arg) {
    return arg !== un && arg !== nl && (arg === arg);
  }

  function isarray(o) {
    return isfn(Array.isArray) ? Array.isArray(o) : Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === '[object Array]';
  }

  function slc(a, i1, i2) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(a, i1, i2);
  }

  function overload(o, method_v1, method_v2) {
    var origm = o[method_v1];
    return o[method_v1] = function() {
      var args = slc(arguments);
      if (method_v2.length === arguments.length) {
        return method_v2.apply(this, args);
      } else if (isfn(origm)) {
        return origm.apply(this, args);
      } else {
        return un;
      }
    };
  }

  function rig_props(obj, props) {
    if (
      isobj(obj) && isplainobj(props)) {
      each(
        props, function(p, v) {
          obj[p] = v;
        })
    }
    return obj;
  }

  function owns(obj, prop) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(prop);
  }

  function each(obj, fn) {
    for (var p in obj) {
      if (owns(obj, p)) {
        if (fn.call(obj, p, obj[p]) === f) break;
      }
    }
    return obj;
  }

  function vacate_obj(obj) {
    if (isobj(obj)) {
      for (var p in obj) {
        try {
          if (!owns(Object.prototype, p)) {
            delete obj[p];
          }
        } catch (xc) {}
      }
    }
    return obj;
  }

  function extend(hostObj, obj) {
    each(
      obj, function(prop) {
        if (owns(hostObj, prop) && isobj(hostObj[prop])) {
          if (isobj(this[prop])) {
            if (!isarray(this[prop])) {
              if (
                isplainobj(this[prop]) && isplainobj(hostObj[prop])) {
                extend(hostObj[prop], this[prop]);
              } else {
                hostObj[prop] = this[prop];
              }
            } else if (isarray(this[prop])) {
              if (isarray(hostObj[prop])) {
                this[prop].each(

                  function(k, v) {
                    hostObj[prop].has(v) || hostObj[prop].push(v);
                  });
              } else {
                hostObj[prop] = this[prop];
              }
            } else {
              hostObj[prop] = this[prop];
            }
          } else {
            hostObj[prop] = this[prop];
          }
        } else {
          hostObj[prop] = this[prop];
        }
      });
    return hostObj;
  }
  //
  //
  // declare main fn
  //  accepts any object
  _db = function(obj) {

    if (
      isobj(obj) && !_dbs.has(obj)) {
      (function(_d) {

        var host = this,
          dtfn = "data";

        // if no arguments are provided  return private data store
        // else pass responsibility to overloaded fns
        this[dtfn] = function() {
          return (arguments.length === 0) ? _d : host[dtfn](arguments[0], arguments[1]);
        };

        // if one argument is provided deal with reading data value
        // or if plain object is provided extend data store with provided obj's props
        overload(
          this, dtfn, function(dtk) {
            return isplainobj(dtk) && (extend(_d, dtk), host) || _d[dtk];
          });

        // if two arguments are given handle setting a data property
        // if value to set and current data value are objs extend current data value
        // else set data value to given parameter
        overload(
          this, dtfn, function(dtk, dtv) {
            isplainobj(dtv) && (
              isplainobj(_d[dtk]) && (extend(_d[dtk], dtv), t) || (_d[dtk] = dtv), t) || (_d[dtk] = dtv);
            return host;
          });

        // attach utility fns to data method
        rig_props(
          this[dtfn], {
            alter: function(dt) {
              return (
                isplainobj(dt) && (_d = dt), host);
            },
            drop: function(dtk) {
              isvalid(dtk) && (delete _d[dtk], t) || vacate_obj(_d);
              return host;
            },
            has: function(dtk) {
              return isvalid(dtk) ? owns(_d, dtk['valueOf']()) : un;
            },
            each: function(fn) {
              if (isfn(fn)) {
                each(
                  _d, function(p, v) {
                    return fn.call(host, p, v);
                  });
              }
              return host;
            },
            index: function() {
              var k = [];
              this.each(

                function(p, v) {
                  k.push(p);
                });
              return k;
            }
          });

        // remember configured object to avoid configuration rerun
        _dbs.push(this);
      }).call(obj, {});
    } // end if
    // return configured object
    return obj;
  }

  // attach 'idb' fn identifier to global scope
  _host_.idb = _db;

})(self);
//
//
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to do this, what does this add over standard JS objects, all you would need is add `Object.prototype.alter` and `Object.prototype.forEach`.

From a once over:

- If you are going to have `f` -> `false` and `t` -> `true`, then you might as well point to them `true` and `false` instead of `!0` and `!t`
- Variables like `nl` for `null` are unfortunate, it reduces the quality of your code
- Your prototype `each` should probably be `forEach` and only be set if `forEach` is not already there ( it is there for more most browsers )
- You should use lowerCamelCase: `isarray` -> `isArray` etc.
- You are overdoing the newlines:

  ```
  function rig_props( obj, props ) {
      if (
          isobj( obj )
          && isplainobj( props )
      ) {
          each(
              props,
              function ( p, v ) {
                  obj[p] = v;
              }
          )
      }
      return obj;
  }
  ```

  should be

  ```
  function rigPropertiess( o, properties ) {
      if ( isObject( o ) && isPlainObject( properties ){
          each( properties, function ( key, value ) {
                  o[key] = value;
          });
      }
      return o;
  }
  ```
- `vacate_obj` worries me, why would you need this compare to just assigning a new object ?
- `extend` has a severe case of arrow pattern coding:

  ```
                              } else {
                                  hostObj[prop] = this[prop];
                              }
                          } else {
                              hostObj[prop] = this[prop];
                          }
                      } else {
                          hostObj[prop] = this[prop];
                      }
                  } else {
                      hostObj[prop] = this[prop];
                  }
              }
          );
      return hostObj;
  }
  ```

  I am sure that with some deep thoughts you can do this better

Again, I think you are re-inventing the wheel, unless I am missing something.

Comment: useful hints. I guess abandoning bad habits is pretty tough stuff. +